# HttpRequestBegin pipeline not working in SXA multisite

Tags: sxa, pipelines, multisite

I have installed Sitecore 9.1.1 locally with the domain as "sc911" and in this instance I have installed the client's multisites (using a script that installs the packages), built using SXA. Now I created an `httpRequestBegin` pipeline and put the patch file in the `/include` folder.

Now when I try to access the site using https://sc911 then my processor method gets hit on the debugger attached, but out of multisite I have one site with the domain as "local.cm.mywebsite.com" and it works fine (means pages are working) but it is not hitting the processor method that I override.

One thing I noticed that when hit https://local.cm.mywebsite.com/sitecore then my processor method gets hit on the debugger attached.

Do you have any idea why is this weird behavior, or I am missing any configuration?

I want my processor to be executed for the https://local.cm.mywebsite.com url and the other pages built under this website.

**EDIT:** Below is the screenshot of the code snippet for the processor that I have created, this has some logic like it checks the url and on the basis of the url it redirects to some other url on the basis of few checks.

[image]

FYI: This processor gets hit on the debugger when I request any page inside the /sitecore url (e.g. https://local.cm.mywebsite.com/sitecore/admin/.......) but when I request a page in the site (e.g. https://local.cm.mywebsite.com/my-site-pages) then the debugger is not getting hit.

Below is the configuration:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <pipelines>
            <httpRequestBegin>
                <processor patch:after="*[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.SiteResolver, Sitecore.Kernel']" type="aaa.Web.Foundation.Pipelines.Pipelines.HttpRequestBegin.RedirectProcessor, aaa.Web.Foundation.Pipelines" />
            </httpRequestBegin>
        </pipelines>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

**NOTE:** I have checked the namespace and assembly name, it is all correct in the config therefore debugger is getting hit for the /Sitecore/...... urls.

Comment: What do you mean by "I have installed the client's multisites"?

Comment: What have you overwritten? How is it configured?

Comment: Mark Cassidy, I mean I have installed the packages that has tenant structure for the websites in SXA

Comment: @Gatogordo, I have edited the question to provide more info.

Comment: Your config is weird.. SXA removes the processor you are referring and uses "Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite.Pipelines.HttpRequest.SiteResolver" instead. Check your /admin/showconfig.aspx to see if your processor is where it should be.

Comment: Thanks @Gatogordo for your reply I will try this and I need the confirmation regarding the assembly name also please. Whether it should be Sitecore.kernel only or any other like Sitecore.XA. Foundation.Pipeline?

Comment: Yes, this worked @Gatogordo. Thanks, I upvoted and marked the answer as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have SXA installed, this will remove the default SiteResolver from the configuration so your config patch will not be working correctly.

Try to patch like this:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <pipelines>
            <httpRequestBegin>
                <processor patch:after="*[@type='Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite.Pipelines.HttpRequest.SiteResolver, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite']" type="aaa.Web.Foundation.Pipelines.Pipelines.HttpRequestBegin.RedirectProcessor, aaa.Web.Foundation.Pipelines" />
            </httpRequestBegin>
        </pipelines>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

This should put your resolver just after the SiteResolver from SXA. Verify with `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` to make sure your configuration is correct.

A resolver at that place in the pipeline should be executed, also on SXA sites.